# How to configure a DisclosureGroup inside ScrollView to allow more space for other views when Disclosure is contracted?

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, disclosuregroup

I have a situation that has been, approximately, reproduced in the code below.

`TopView()` shows some text with a min scale factor. `BottomView()` shows other text in a `DisclosureGroup` which is inside a `Scrollview`. The text in `TopView()` is getting compressed (due to the min scale factor). I would like for it to expand to full font when the disclosure group is not expanded and contract when the `DisclosureGroup` is expanded.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MainApp: App {
  
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      VStack(spacing: 8) {
        TopView()
        BottomView()
      }
    }
  }
}

struct TopView: View {
  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
      VStack(spacing: 8) {
        ForEach(0 ..< 15) { int in
          Text("\(int)")
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .font(.system(size: 75))
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.50)
            .background(int % 2 == 0 ? .green : .red)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        }
        .padding(0)
      }
    }
//    .layoutPriority(1)
  }
}

struct BottomView: View {
  @State var isExpanded = true
  
  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
      ScrollView {
        DisclosureGroup("Sample disclosure", isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
          ForEach(21 ..< 40) { int in
            Text("\(int)")
              .foregroundColor(.black)
              .font(.system(size: 75))
              .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
          }
        }
        .font(.title)
        .padding()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a screenshot with the disclosure expanded and the TopView() compressed.
[image]

Here's a screenshot with the disclosure not expanded and the TopView() stays compressed. How can I configure the ScrollView/DisclosureGroup to move down when contracted so there's more space for TopView()?
[image]

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: Not yet ... will do so this weekend. Looks promising ... any reason behind saving the safeAreaInsets?

Comment: No, sorry. I was using it before but then I forgot to remove it.

Comment: How did you come up with the 50 for non-expanded maxHeight?

Comment: It seemed ok to my eye. Actually that was why I was using the safe area. But didn't work as expected, so I used 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the isExpanded property for that:

```
struct BottomView: View {
    @State var isExpanded = true
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                DisclosureGroup("Sample disclosure", isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
                    ForEach(21 ..< 40) { int in
                        Text("\(int)")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .font(.system(size: 75))
                            .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                    }
                }
                .font(.title)
                .padding()
                
            }
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: isExpanded ? .infinity : 50) // <-- Add this line to the GeometryReader
    }
}
```

In this way the BottomView will take about half the space of the screen when expanded, and when contracted it will go to the bottom of the screen leaving more space for other Views.

Comment: This works. Simply need perhaps a better way to determine the frame height which could be determined based on the height of the font being used. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I agree with you. I just wanted to point you in the right direction.